# Update Closing_Balance based on previous row value

Tags: sql, sql-server, lag

I am having the table which contains ID, Opening_Balnce and Closing Balance columns as follows. This is existing table maintained by our clients and OB referes the amount which needs to add/subtract to the previous row cb.. for example if i receive 100 rs from the vendor then i need to add 100 as ob and 600 as cb.

```
   ID   OB    CB
   ===============
    1   100   100
    2   100   200
    3   100   300
    4   100   400
    5   -100  300
    6   100   400
    7   100   500
    8   -100  400
```

If i update/delete some row in middle, the closing balance should get update based on previous row vales.

For example, I am going to update OB = 200 for ID = 4, so the ouput should be as follows:

```
   ID   OB    CB
   ===============
    1   100   100
    2   100   200
    3   100   300
    4   200   500
    5   -100  400
    6   100   500
    7   100   600
    8   -100  500
```

I have tried following sql attempt which is not working in single shot

```
UPDATE A 
SET OB = 200, CB = OB + PrevCB
FROM A JOIN (SELECT LAG(CB) OVER (ORDER BY ID)PrevCB, ID FROM A) X ON A.ID = X.ID 
WHERE A.ID = 4;

UPDATE A
SET CB = OB + PrevCB
FROM A JOIN (SELECT LAG(CB) OVER (ORDER BY ID)PrevCB, ID FROM A) X ON A.ID = X.ID 
WHERE A.ID > 4;
```

Comment: This is a very strange data structure.  Why does it not include the *amount* on each row (presumably the difference between `cb` and `ob`?  How can you change `ob` without changing previous rows?

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is existing table maintained by our clients and OB referes the amount which needs to add/subtract to the previous row cb.. for example if i receive 100 rs from the vendor then i need to add 100 as ob and 600 as cb.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `SUM` window function.

```
UPDATE T 
SET OB = 200
FROM T 
WHERE ID = 4;

UPDATE T
SET CB = val + (SELECT CB FROM T WHERE ID = 3)
FROM T JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(OB) over(order by ID) val, ID 
    FROM T
    WHERE ID > 3
) X ON T.ID = X.ID
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=537b248b6ef1c46b3f9629253c7eb3cb)

**Result**

```
 ID   OB    CB
 ===============
    1   100   100
    2   100   200
    3   100   300
    4   200   500
    5   -100  400
    6   100   500
    7   100   600
    8   -100  500
```

Comment: Hi, This is looks somehwhat ok but still you have used id=3 in subquery because that id should be dynamic.. the previous id value can be anything either 3 or 2 or 1.